# Command '.NET: Generate Assets for Build and Debug' resulted in an error (command 'dotnet.generateAssets' not found)

Tags: c#, omnisharp

I am a student and was interested in game dev so I started learning c# with a brackley video. It was all going well but I came across thing issue *"Unable to generate assets... OMnisharp server not running"* I looked online solved that issue but then this came *"Command '.NET: Generate Assets for Build and Debug' resulted in an error (command 'dotnet.generateAssets' not found)"*

---

So far i have tried

- An old version of C# extension
- Reistall